# Can't Resume Flows

Tags: process-builder, data-loader, account, visual-workflow

**I have several Process Builders and a couple directly-written Flows in our Org.**

I'm currently *data loading 275k records over the weekend*.  Estimates show it should be done (if I don't find it stopped and have to restart) around 2am Sunday morning.  The records are Accounts (with heavy Apex involvement by managed-package "Rootstock").

I've noticed that the Flows that are pending due to these inserts (batch size = 5) are **coming in PAUSED**.  They are now as old as almost 2 hours ago, when I started the upload, and growing.  None of these flows (after the first few) are ever Resuming it appears.

If I visit a specific Flow, it only has Delete, no Resume option (also checked the page layout - Resume is there).  I am Sys Admin.

**Is there some correlation between loading a lot of data, and Flows "waiting" for a break in the influx of "new Flows"**, or anything like that?  I'm finding no topic that remotely covers this no matter how hard i search.

**[ [ As of June 16 2017 @ 4pm, I cannot attach a screenshot due to the site complaining about my 80k file ] ]**

Comment: So far, all I know is this:   (1) the queued Flows were from Process Builder - a "time delay" execution for "2 hours before create date" (which causes it to happen appx 1 minute after creation).....  (2) after 50k records loaded (it aborted then), the queued Flows started processing, but literally took over a day to "all fail" (reason for failure has to do with complications caused by Rootstock's Apex).   I know how I'm going to work around this during the next load, but I'm still confused as to why they queued to begin with for more than appx a minute - PROBABLY due to loading thousands.